# Latex table multiple row and multiple column

Tags: latex, multiple-columns, tabular, multirow

I'm trying to create a table in Latex but without success. I tried different solutions but no one solves my problem.
I would like create a table like the picture below:

[image]

Can anyone show how to do this in Latex please?

Comment: Be careful with tables. Don't imprison your data in a grid of cells. [Data looks better naked](http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/data-looks-better-naked/). Also see Tufte's [concept of presenting tabular data.](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0000Jr)

Comment: In the comunity http://tex.stackexchange.com you can search for more examples. :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One first sketch may be the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User B} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User C} & \multirow{3}{*}{D}\\
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \\
\cline{2-5}
 & B1 & B2 & C1 & C2 & \\
\hline
 & & & & & \\
\hline
 & & & & & \\
\hline
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image: screenshot of output]

**Addendum:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily %
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}% seven columns now, not six...
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User B} & \multirow{3}{*}{X} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User C} & \multirow{3}{*}{D}\\
\cline{2-3}\cline{5-6}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \\
\cline{2-3}\cline{5-6}
 & B1 & B2 & & C1 & C2 & \\
\hline
 & & & & & & \\
\hline
 & & & & & & \\
\hline
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}
}%

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Please, *critically* check all the differences between the original code and this latter.

Don't forget that several LaTeX packages can help you improving style, dimensions and spacing of your table: among these, I advise you to have a look at [`bigstrut`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigstrut).

Also:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & \multirow{3}{*}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User C} & \multirow{3}{*}{D}\\
\cline{3-6}
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \\
\cline{3-6}
 & & B1 & B2 & C1 & C2 & \\
\hline
 & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You should now be able to operate on your own further changes to the model of table.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the **multirow package**:

http://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/

You have to include the library:

```latex
%multi-column
\multicolumn{number cols}{align}{text} % align: l,c,r

%multi-row
\usepackage{multirow}

\multirow{number rows}{width}{text}
```

Then it looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Multi-column and multi-row table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Multi-col-row}}&X\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&X\\
    \hline
    X&X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

*note: code examples from the link provided*