# How to split a cell in a table in latex?

Tags: latex, tabular

I am wanting to create a table as a header in LaTeX. 3 columns, the first cell must span two rows, the second cell must span two rows and the third cell must be split between the two rows. So 4 cells total but 3 columns like the picture below. Im having trouble with the spacing when I try and split the last column into two rows.

[image: Table picture]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One first sketch:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Some text A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Some text B} & Some text C\\
\cline{3-3}
 & & Some text D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives you:

[image: screenshot of table]

It is not clear to me if you want your middle column to be larger than the two on the sides. Anyway, see [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291026/latex-table-multiple-row-and-multiple-column/32291618#32291618)!

Comment: Many thanks. When using \centering for text C and D it shifts the clone to the first cell. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @DuncanWilliamGibbons text C and text D are centered by default (check it with a longer text)...and I think \centering within one cell is not the way

Answer (score 1):

The `tabularray` package makes merging cells very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={lXc},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
\SetCell[r=2]{} some text & \SetCell[r=2]{} some long text some long text some long text & short text\\
&& short text\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```