# Splitting a column of a table in Latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I want to create something like this:

[image]

Can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package, but don't try to split, merge the top right cell instead.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291618/3543233) too. Here's a sketch for you, using indeed [`multirow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3}\\
\cline{3-4}
                   &                    & 3a & 3b\\
\hline
                   &                    &    & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, the `tabularray` packages makes it really easy to merge cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={cccc},
  vlines,
  hlines,
}
\SetCell[r=2]{} 1 & \SetCell[r=2]{} 2 & \SetCell[c=2]{} 3\\
& & 3a & 3b\\
& & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]